# Как организовать v-bind по клику на инпут?

Tags: vue.js

Как организовать v-bind по клику на инпут?
Тот на который мы кликнули его border будет зеленый
Активный border в input может быть только один
Тоесть кликнули на name - input style - border, кликнули на phone - (border - style input phone), но пропадает на name

Comment: так сделайте на css используя `:focus`

Comment: input:focus  {}   ?